# UITableView indexPath.row issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a tableView which loads a custom UITableViewCell with a "Tap" button inside it. A method is called when user clicks the button.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{...
    [btnRowTap addTarget:self action:@selector(didButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 ...
return cell;
}
```

In the didButtonTouchUpInside method, Im trying to retrieve the value of row selected in the following way:

```
-(IBAction)didButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)btn.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [matchingCustTable indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
}
```

The problem is that on clicking button at any row, I am getting the same value of 0 every time.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Presuming you correctly adding the button to the contentView calling `UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)btn.superview;` will only give you the contentView not the cell.

Comment: At the very least you'd want to traverse up the superviews until you find the UITableViewCell but personally I'd go with [Nitin Gohel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18508218/2613662).

Comment: You should check if indexPath is nil. Most likely indexPath.row is 0 all the time because indexPath is nil!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must **NOT** rely on the view hierarchy of a UITableViewCell. This approach will fail in iOS7, because iOS7 changes the view hierarchy of the cell. There will be an additional view between your button and the UITableViewCell.

There are better ways to handle this.

1. Convert the button frame so it is relative to the tableview
2. ask the tableView for the indexPath at the origin of the new frame

.

```
-(IBAction)didButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
    CGRect buttonFrameInTableView = [btn convertRect:btn.bounds toView:matchingCustTable];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [matchingCustTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonFrameInTableView.origin];

    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: as stated, I can confirm the view hierarchy does indeed fail in ios7. Matthias' method works (thanks for posting).

Answer (score 5):

set Button tag in to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method Befor setting Method like

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{...
    btnRowTap.tag=indexPath.row
    [btnRowTap addTarget:self action:@selector(didButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 ...
return cell;
}
```

and your tapped cell getting like this:-

```
-(IBAction)didButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender{
{
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
        NSIndexPath *indPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
        //Type cast it to CustomCell
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tblView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indPath];
        NSLog(@"%d",indPath.row);

}
```

Comment: +1 for using tags to identify the row index. Other answers seem to use the button's superview which generally makes me worry as the view hierarchy could change.

Comment: Yup. It will work fine. I instead had a label and I was setting its tag and doing the same thing. But I just wanted to know the reason why Im getting it wrong.

Comment: @SteveWilford Yes. And this year, for the first time, the view hierarchy of a UITableViewCell will actually change. And all those superview.superview.superview methods will fail. Some will fail silently, some will lead to crashes.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,if you are adding button to cell content view then use below code.

```
 UITableViewCell *buttonCell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview;
    UITableView* table1 = (UITableView *)[buttonCell superview];
    NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [table1 indexPathForCell:buttonCell];
    int rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
    int sectionOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell section];
```

Comment: Protip: This will cause an unknown selector exception in a certain unreleased mobile operating system.

Comment: Thanks, Its working perfectly. @Sunny for the answer and kirsteins for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

`btn.superview` is `contentView` of `UITableviewCell`. Use `btn.superview.superview` instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you already knew the value inside the cell, then

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 UITableViewCell *currentCell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([currentCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Your Cell Text value" ]){
//Do theStuff here
 }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for your ibAction.you dont need to set any tag or anything else

```
 -(IBAction)didButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender{
  NSIndexPath *indexPath =
        [tbl
         indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
}
```