# Assigning UItableView cell tags when using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have three prototype cells defined in my storyboard containing a `UISegmentedControl` widget in each one. I have two types of criteria to present the user with; one is `[ON|OFF]` the other is `[1|2|3|4]`. I need to set the text of each widget progmatically so I am setting the widget `Tag` in the storyboard in order to obtain the widget from the correct prototype cell using `[cell viewWithTag:XX]`. The problem is, all my `UISegmentedControl` widgets are wired up to the same listener and I have no way of telling which criteria the user is turning on or off. I've seen the `Tag` value set to the row number in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but I'm already using the `Tag` in the storyboard. How can I tell which row is being interacted with in my listener?

UPDATE: code snip added

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *retcell;
   NSInteger thisrow = indexPath.row;

   // retrieve the items which should be printed for this
   // row. set text on widget depending on item type
   OBJ_Items *items = [mCriteria objectForKey:thisrow];

   if ([items.Type isEqualToString:YESNO])
   {
      retcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yesno"];

      // get a handle to the widget in this cell in order to access it's Text property
      UISegmentedControl *yesno = (UISegmentedControl *)[retcell viewWithTag:200];

      // .. set text for yesno segments

      // save the row numer to this object's tag so we can retrieve the item object
      // on click
      [yesno setTag:thisrow];

   }
   if ([items.Type isEqualToString:SETTING])
   {
      retcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"setting"];
      UISegmentedControl *setting = (UISegmentedControl *)[retcell viewWithTag:201];
      // set text for segments...
      [setting setTag:thisrow];
   }

return (retcell);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using tags to identify prototype cells, you should use reuse identifiers for that task.

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining my question clearly. I've re-worded it and added a code snippet. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you should make some `UITableViewCell` subclasses for your `YESNO` cell and `SETTING` cell. Then in `tableView:cellForRow:atIndexPath:`, return either a `YESNOTableViewCell` or a `SETTINGTableViewCell`. Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *retcell;
   NSInteger thisrow = indexPath.row;

   // retrieve the items which should be printed for this
   // row. set text on widget depending on item type
   OBJ_Items *items = [mCriteria objectForKey:thisrow];

   if ([items.Type isEqualToString:YESNO])
   {
      YESNOTableViewCell yesNoCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yesno"];

      // .. set text for yesno segments
      // the UISegmentedControl will be an IBOutlet @property on YESNOTableViewCell

      // save the row numer to this object's tag so we can retrieve the item object
      // on click
      [yesNoCell.segmentedControl setTag:thisrow];

      // return the yesNoCell
      retcell = yesNoCell;

   }
   if ([items.Type isEqualToString:SETTING])
   {
      SETTINGTableViewCell settingCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"setting"];

      // set text for segments...
      // the UISegmentedControl will be an IBOutlet @property on SETTINGTableViewCell

      [settingCell.setting setTag:thisrow];
   }

return (retcell);
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. that's an interesting approach.. So in my subclass I could simply add a method called `setTableRow` or `getTableRow` and set that property accordingly? I think that may be what I needed to get un-stuck here. thanks!

Comment: Another approach I found is use `addTarget` on the  `UISegementedController` and retrieve the row selected inside the selector. Still need to implement an `IBOutlet` on the table view but no need to do the subclassing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508183/uitableview-indexpath-row-issue